# How to add image into table data,without affecting other tables?

Tags: html, css

Here's what im trying to do:  http://piclair.com/nj6h3

Im want so image would not make boxes: Total kills:  Total deaths: Total assists: Record dmg to champions: Times played:
bigger.

```
<?php 
echo '<strong><a href="champrofile.php?name='.$champ_name.'">'.$row['name'].'</a></strong> -<img src='.$row['profile'].' id="champ_image"> </td> '; 
?>

.box {
        border:1px solid black;
        padding:2px;
        padding-right:5px;
        position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Im sorry i posted an answer. I thought u have a problem with the image position in the table, not with the content in the image. Coudl you explain better what result you are expecting?

Comment: Please update your code so we can assist.... Post the whole table section